# jquery draggable and changing the color of the background container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm getting a syntax error because obviously i am doing something wrong.

Here is the code:

```
 <style>
    body{margin:0 auto;}
    .draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em;background-color:red;}     

    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
    });
    var i=0;
    $(".draggable").each(function(i){
     if(i%2==0){
        #container("background-color:green");
       }
       i++;
       });
    </script>
 </head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width:100%;height:400px;background-      color:#ccc;position:relative;">
<div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="margin-top:10%;margin-    left:1%;position:absolute;">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
<div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="margin-top:10%;margin-    left:20%;position:absolute;">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
<div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"style="margin-top:10%;margin-    left:33%;position:absolute;" >
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
<div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"style="margin-top:10%;margin-    left:45%;position:absolute;" >
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
<div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"style="margin-top:10%;margin-    left:60%;position:absolute;" >
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
<div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="margin-top:10%;margin-    left:80%;position:absolute;">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
</div>
```

In the web developer tool the syntax error is here:

#container("background-color:green");

What I need to do is when the draggable div is moved out of the container, if the number of draggable divs remaining in the container is odd, the background color of the container turns green.

Regards,
umbre gachoong

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
#container("background-color:green");
```

with

```
$("#container").css("background-color", "green");
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Made the change but the container background color does not change. I think it must be the logic i am using here.

Comment: Move the <script> ... </script> to the bottom of the code, just before the body ends.

Comment: Thanks Enve. I moved it now the background color is green without moving the draggable divs. http://inetwebdesign.com/draggable_example2.html

Comment: and now I have been told there is an added requirement. Before the divs can be counted as odd or even, they must be fully in the container. If they are half in or out of the container, they do not count. Ugh